# Can't delete PWA cache completely

Tags: progressive-web-apps, browser-cache

I am working on a PWA, and I want to purge the cache completely every time I update the service worker. I have tried several strategies, but every time I delete a cache I can see items in the new cache with a timestamp older than the time of its creation.

For example, if I create a new cache at `14:00:00`, I can see items with e.g. `14:00:02` timestamps, but also see items with e.g. `08:15:26` timestamps, which is way earlier than the time I even created the cache.

I have found the same question on SO multiple times, but there were no answers, so I post it again. Maybe it will catch someone's attention.

**Strategy #1: Deleting the entire cache by its name then recaching**

```
self.addEventListener("install", (e) => {
    e.waitUntil(caches.delete("appCache").then(() => {
        caches.open("appCache").then((cache) => {
            cache.addAll(stuffToCache);
        });
    }));
});
```

**Strategy #2: Deleting cached items by their keys then recaching**

```
self.addEventListener("install", (e) => {
    e.waitUntil(caches.open("appCache").then((cache) => {
        cache.keys().then((keys) => {
            keys.forEach((request) => {
                cache.delete(request);
            });
        }).finally(() => {
            cache.addAll(stuffToCache);
        });
    }));
});
```

**Strategy #3: Using versioned caches**

```
const date = new Date().toISOString();

self.addEventListener("install", (e) => {   
    e.waitUntil(caches.open(`appCache-${date}`).then((cache) => {
        cache.addAll(stuffToCache);
    }));
});

self.addEventListener("activate", (e) => {
    e.waitUntil(caches.keys().then((keys) => {
        keys.forEach((key) => {
            if (key !== `appCache-${date}`) {
                caches.delete(key);
            }
        });
    }));
});
```

With all 3 strategies I use a *network first* dynamic caching. (`<CACHE NAME>` is `appCache` or `appCache-${version.date}`, depending on the strategy.)

```
self.addEventListener("fetch", (e) => {
    e.respondWith(caches.open(<CACHE NAME>).then((cache) => {
        return fetch(e.request).then((response) => {
            cache.put(e.request, response.clone());
            return response;
        });
    }));
});
```

What the heck am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

can you check if this method is working for you? It's working for me. It uses version. Filter out old cache keys and then delete them.

```
// cleanup old caches except precache
    self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
       event.waitUntil(
       caches.keys().then(cacheKeys => {
        const oldKeys = cacheKeys.filter(key =>
                         key.indexOf(<CACHE_NAME>) === -1 && key.indexOf(version) === -1,
                        );
        const deletePromises = oldKeys.map(oldKey => caches.delete(oldKey));
        return Promise.all(deletePromises);
       }),
     );
    });
```

Comment: How does it differ from my solution in terms of seemingly keeping old chached values? My strategy #3 also deletes caches with old versions, but in the newly created cache there are old items.

Comment: the old items may be precache items that's why I mentioned that my method will delete the cache but not the items that are preached during load.

Comment: My app uses a single cache and I want to delete the whole content, not just certain items.